# Почему не загружаются файлы в google cloud storage?

Tags: laravel, google-cloud

Laravel 9

Используется плагин spatie/laravel-google-cloud-storage~2.0 для загрузки на google storage

Конфиг в filesystems.php (все данные и доступы к json с данными проверены несколько раз)

```
    'gcs' => [
                'driver' => 'gcs',
                'key_file_path' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE', '/var/www/bucket-loader.json'), // optional: /path/to/service-account.json
                'key_file' => [], // optional: Array of data that substitutes the .json file (see below)
                'project_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID', 'your-project-id'), // optional: is included in key file
                'bucket' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET', 'your-bucket'),
                'path_prefix' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_PATH_PREFIX', 'test'), // optional: /default/path/to/apply/in/bucket
                'apiEndpoint' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_API_URI', null), // see: Public URLs below
                'visibility' => 'public', // optional: public|private
                'metadata' => ['cacheControl'=> 'public,max-age=86400'], // optional: default metadata
            ],
```

Код загрузки изображения, идет получения изображения, генерируется изображение, а после загружается на google storage

```
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $name= uniqid().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
    $disk = Storage::disk('gcs');
    
    var_dump($disk->put($name, file_get_contents($file)));
```

После попытки загрузки ответ приходит false, не ошибка авторизации, ничего более, просто false

Права у сервисного аккаунта который подключен к нужному ведру выставлены вот такие
Storage Admin
Storage Object Admin
Storage Object Creator
Storage Object Viewer

Не совсем понимаю почему не загружаются файлы, возможно у вас есть мысли по этому поводу, если информации недостаточно, пишите, я быстро вам дам более детальную информацию

Спасибо вам за помощь в нелегком вопросе

Comment: `$disk->put($name, file_get_contents($request->file('file')->getRealPath()))`

Comment: @InDevX к сожалению не помогло, все так же не загружается и возвращает false

Comment: Уверены что файл прилетает? Проверьте путь выше, возможно там не getRealPath() надо а другое, по памяти написал. И попробуйте ещё без file_get_contents()

Comment: @InDevX Да, поскольку попробовал только что $disk->put("text.txt", 'test') просто создать файл, но он так же возвращает false и так же нет файла.

Comment: Если то что вы написали не получается значит не там ошибку ищите. Проверьте соединение, если не знаете как - добавьте ошибку в кредах чтоб получить ошибку авторизации и убедиться что вы не авторизованы

Comment: @InDevX Спасибо большое за советы, сейчас попробую так сделать